# UWP Reference Issue SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

> Could not find SDK "SQLite.UWP.2015, Version=3.13,1"

[image: Error in Soluton Explorer]

I'm using C#.

I tried to reference it after downloading and installing `sqlite-uwp-3150000.vsix`. I had an older version of sqlite referenced before installing it.

An answer to this question must provide a solution to this questions:

How can I uninstall the package (where is it located) and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't know, what programming language you are using, so you'll have to find the project file yourself. You can then manually edit the file to reference the correct version (`3.13,1` looks wrong anyway). Fixing this through the IDE is also different depending on the programming language you use. You should provide that information in your question.

Comment: @IInspectable Updated the post with required information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have installed `sqlite-uwp-3150000.vsix`, the you should be able to find "**SQLite for Universal Windows Platform 3.15.0**" under **"Reference Manager"**.
[image]

We can add this new version by right click **"References"** then select **"Add Reference" → "Universal Windows" → "Extensions"**.

To solve your issue, you can just remove the reference of the older version by choosing the older version in **"References"** and then right click and click "**Remove**".
[image]

After this, the error should be solved. There is no need to uninstall the older version. But usually, you can find it under:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.UWP.2015

[image]

You can delete the old version as you want.